# Most efficient way to find mode in an array using python? Return type is an array of integers

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

Here is my solution, which works in O(N) time and O(N) space:

```
def find_mode(array):
    myDict = {}
    result = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] in myDict:
            myDict[array[i]] += 1
        else:
            myDict[array[i]] = 1

    maximum = max(myDict.values())
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if value == maximum:
            result.append(key)
    
    return result
```

I can't think of a more efficient solution than O(N) but if anyone has any improvements to this function please let me know. **The return type is an array of integers.**

Comment: "improvements" is a vague term, what are you specifically looking for? Faster runtime? Constant space?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for faster runtime and/or constant space

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: You can't beat linear time since you'll have to examine each element at least once. I also disagree that this is a good question for CR.SE, since this is about a specific optimization.

Comment: If you just want an algorithm with better complexity, this has been asked before here: [Finding the relative majority, deterministically in O(n) time and O(1) space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781720/most-common-element-in-an-array-finding-the-relative-majority-deterministical). If you want to improve your specific Python function, then Code Review may be a better place to ask. However, it's doubtful that you'll get better space complexity, since the O(n) runtime is dependent on your model of computation to begin with (i.e., hashing is allowed).

Comment: This implementation is really not bad at all, but you should use https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

First, you should note that `O(n)` worst-case time cannot be improved upon with a deterministic, non-randomized algorithm, since we may need to check all elements.

Second, since you want *all modes*, not just one, the best space complexity of any possible algorithm is `O(|output|)`, not `O(1)`.

Third, this is as hard as the [Element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem). This implies that any algorithm that is 'expressible' in terms of decision trees only, can at best achieve `Omega(n log n)` runtime. To beat this, you need to be able to hash elements or use numbers to index the computer's memory or some other non-combinatorial operation. This isn't a rigorous proof that `O(|output|)` space complexity with `O(n)` time is impossible, but it means you'll need to specify a model of computation to get a more precise bound on runtime, or specify bounds on the range of integers in your array.

Lastly, and most importantly, you should [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) your code if you are worried about performance. If this is truly the bottleneck in your program, then Python may not be the right language to achieve the absolute minimum number of operations needed to solve this problem.

Here's a more Pythonic approach, using the standard library's very useful [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). The Counter initialization (in CPython) is usually done through a `C` function, which will be faster than your `for` loop. It is still `O(n)` time and space, though.

```py
def find_mode(array: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    counts = collections.Counter(array)
    maximum = max(counts.values())
    return [key for key, value in counts.items()
            if value == maximum]
```